# Не могу получить значение input методом val()

Tags: jquery

Всем, привет! Уважаемое сообщество, прошу вашей помощи. Возникла трудность с получением значения из `input` с помощью метода `val()`.

Есть `DIV` который содержит `inputы:

[image]

Вот его разметка:

```
<div class="input-daterange input-group afc" id="datepicker-common-table">
   <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="start" placeholder="Начальная дата">
   <span class="input-group-addon"> - </span>
   <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="end" placeholder="Конечная дата">
</div>
```

Вот сценарий которым пытаюсь получить значения после их установки:

```
$(document).on('change', "input[name='start']", function()
{       
   $(document).on('change', "input[name='end']", function()
   {
      var startVal = $("#datepicker-common-table > input:text").val();
      var endVal = $("#datepicker-common-table > input:text").val();
      console.log( startVal + " - " + endVal );
   });
});
```

В итоге в консоль получаю следующий вывод:

[image]

Comment: Вот этот код пытается получить значения одного и того же элемента

      var startVal = $("#datepicker-common-table > input:text").val();
      var endVal = $("#datepicker-common-table > input:text").val();

... с псевдоклассом `:text`, которого никогда не существовало. Вы, наверное, хотели использовать селектор атрибута: `input[type="text"]`. А вот эта конструкция:

    $(document).on('change', "input[name='start']", function()
    {       
       $(document).on('change', "input[name='end']", function()
       {

Может навесить вам бесконечное число обработчиков. Разберитесь, что такое on().

Comment: я использую плагин bootstrap-datepicker sandbox http://afc.ru/newui_backoffice/# там есть событие changeDate http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/events.html#changedate оно не работает тоже

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, значения `startVal` и `endVal` у вас изменятся только при изменении второй даты, а при изменении первой будут назначаться ненужные обработчики событий.

Во-вторых, вы неправавильно находите input'ы start и end. Нужно использовать `input[type="text"]` вместо `input:text`, но даже так в них обоих будет содержаться массив с двумя input'ами start и end.

Это можно переписать так:

```
$('input[name="start"').on('change', onChange);     
$('input[name="end"]').on('change', onChange);

function onChange () {
  var startVal = $('input[name="start"]').val();
  var endVal = $('input[name="end"]').val();
  console.log( startVal + " - " + endVal );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```
$("input[name='start']").datepicker({
dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
showOtherMonths: true,
firstDay: 1,
onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
if($('input[name='start']').val() == dateText){$('input[name='start']').val('')}
else{$('input[name='start']').val(dateText)};
});
```

То же самое и для `$('input[name='end']')`.

Предлагаю данное как вариант и не более, если есть более правильные и валидные решения- с радостью рассмотрю их.